# Symfony2 how to persist entity with oneToOne relationship

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

How can i persist contact data with the relationship with User

I created the entity USER
the Entity Contact

Contact and data are on relationship OneToOne

the code of the Entity USER

```
<?php

namespace tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table("user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pass", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pass;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set login
     *
     * @param string $login
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get login
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    /**
     * Set pass
     *
     * @param string $pass
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPass($pass)
    {
        $this->pass = $pass;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pass
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPass()
    {
        return $this->pass;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contact = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add contact
     *
     * @param \tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact $contact
     * @return User
     */
    public function addContact(\tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact $contact)
    {
        $this->contact[] = $contact;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove contact
     *
     * @param \tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact $contact
     */
    public function removeContact(\tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact $contact)
    {
        $this->contact->removeElement($contact);
    }

    /**
     * Get contact
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getContact()
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }


}
```

the code of the Entity Contact

```
namespace tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table("contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user ;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="sujet", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sujet;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="texte", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $texte;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set sujet
     *
     * @param string $sujet
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setSujet($sujet)
    {
        $this->sujet = $sujet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sujet
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSujet()
    {
        return $this->sujet;
    }

    /**
     * Set texte
     *
     * @param string $texte
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setTexte($texte)
    {
        $this->texte = $texte;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get texte
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTexte()
    {
        return $this->texte;
    }



    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setUser(\tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

the code of the FormType of UserType

```
<?php

namespace tuto\welcomeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('login','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'test')))
            ->add('pass','text',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),
                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'test')))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tuto_welcomebundle_user';
    }
}
```

the code of the Form UserType

```
<?php

namespace tuto\welcomeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('email','text')
            ->add('sujet','text')
            ->add('texte','textarea')
            ->add('user', new UserType())
            ->add('envoyer','submit',array('attr' => array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')));
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\Contact'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tuto_welcomebundle_contact';`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller file?

Comment: thnx man the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't discuss the logic of your relation, but It looks bidirectional and you have to define the owner and inverse sides using the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` options.

I will answer your question straightforward:

to persist the related object in a     OneToOne 
 relation; user in this case, in your contact class add the cascad option like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="tuto\welcomeBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
 private $user ;
```